# adding custom scripts with custom attributes in angular 6 project

Tags: angular6

I need to add a script(cdn) in a component in my angular project.

on in it

````
        // Start: for drop box
        var dbx = new Dropbox({ accessToken: 'A4fRBcFXasdkpAAAAAdgfdfgdfgAAAAAZBlQ9MJNe81yrTLOCioH-7Ty083asdEQSqTD97s7mLIJH0V', fetch: fetch });
        dbx.filesListFolder({ path: '' })
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
        // End: for dropbox```
````

````
addJsToElementDropbox(src: string, type: string, id: string, key: string): HTMLScriptElement {

    let script:any = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = type;
    script.src = src;
    script.id = id;      
    this.renderer.appendChild(document.body, script);
    return script;

}```
````

This is the script created in the DOM

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs"></script>`

My need is to create a script like this in DOM

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="my-key"></script>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use set attribute set custom attribute

```
addJsToElement1(src: string, type: string): HTMLScriptElement {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('data-app-key', 'Test');
    script.type = type;
    script.src = src;
    this.renderer.appendChild(document.body, script);
return script;
}
```